# Combining SELECT results using WHERE with multi-row variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query is being used to return data:

```
Select top 100 
       cnb.ndc_id, 
       cnb.contract_num_val, 
       cnb.quote_price, 
       cnb.eff_dt, 
       cnb.end_dt, 
       cnb.discount_pct, 
       cnb.rebate_pct
from   [NDC_ATTR] ndc 
  INNER JOIN CONTRACT_NDC_BRG cnb ON ndc.attr_val=cnb.NDC_ID
where ndc.field_id = 69 
and   cnb.contract_ndc_brg_id = @CONT;
```

When I run this, I get an error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I know this is because @CONT has multiple rows. But this is exactly what I need.

I have been looking through posts and it seems that it's discouraged to use loops in SQL. (correct me if I am wrong)

How would I return a union of the query above but each row is returned for each row in @CONT?

EDIT:

@CONT defined:

```
declare @CONT varchar(50) = (   
   SELECT contract_ndc_brg_id
   FROM   contract_ndc_brg
     INNER JOIN ndc ON contract_ndc_brg.ndc_id = ndc.item_pk
   where item_id = @VALUE 
   );
```

Comment: Is @cont a table variable?

Comment: @RThomas It is currently a select statement with one column put in a variable.

Comment: How is `@CONT` defined?

Comment: @dnoeth I have made an edit to the post with it.

Comment: @DavidTunnell So in fact the error is not on the first query you provided, but rather when assigning `@CONT`. you can not assign a variable multiple records, rather add a join on your main query

Comment: @Stephen That is correct, there is no error with the 1st query. Would you show me an example of how to add the JOIN?

Comment: @DavidTunnell SqlZim has already provided it.

Comment: @DavidTunnell Why not add a second inner join, something like: `INNER JOIN CONTRACT_NDC_BRG cnb2`. You can't assign multiple values to @CONT.

Comment: @DavidTunnell Rewrite `@CONT` as either UDF or CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of `@CONT` if you can join to `ndc` in your query like so:

```
select top 100 
   cnb.ndc_id
 , cnb.contract_num_val
 , cnb.quote_price
 , cnb.eff_dt
 , cnb.end_dt
 , cnb.discount_pct
 , cnb.rebate_pct
from [NDC_ATTR] ndc
  inner join CONTRACT_NDC_BRG cnb
    on ndc.attr_val = cnb.NDC_ID
  inner join ndc as i
      on cnb.ndc_id = i.item_pk
where ndc.field_id = 69 
   and i.item_id = @VALUE
```

or converting to use `exists()` like so:

```
select top 100 
   cnb.ndc_id
 , cnb.contract_num_val
 , cnb.quote_price
 , cnb.eff_dt
 , cnb.end_dt
 , cnb.discount_pct
 , cnb.rebate_pct
from [NDC_ATTR] ndc
  inner join CONTRACT_NDC_BRG cnb
    on ndc.attr_val = cnb.NDC_ID
where ndc.field_id = 69 
  and exists (
    select 1
    from ndc as i
    where i.item_pk = cnb.ndc_id
      and i.item_id = @VALUE
    )
```

Comment: The concept is right, the multiple uses of NDC is giong to cause problems.  Once as an alias, once as an actual table name.

Comment: @RThomas Yes, this is what just happened when I was testing just now.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I have just seen your query behind @cont, This should work, but I personally prefer the answer given by SqlZim:

```
declare @CONT TABLE (value varchar(500)) 

SELECT contract_ndc_brg_id
FROM contract_ndc_brg
INNER JOIN ndc
ON contract_ndc_brg.ndc_id = ndc.item_pk
where item_id = @VALUE 

Select top 100 cnb.ndc_id, cnb.contract_num_val, cnb.quote_price,cnb.eff_dt, cnb.end_dt, cnb.discount_pct, cnb.rebate_pct
from [NDC_ATTR] ndc 
INNER JOIN CONTRACT_NDC_BRG cnb
ON ndc.attr_val=cnb.NDC_ID
where ndc.field_id=69 and cnb.contract_ndc_brg_id IN ( @CONT );
```

Comment: This has the same issue if there is more than one row.

Comment: Should be `IN (SELECT contract_ndc_brg_id FROM @CONT)` if you want to use that technique

Answer (score 2):

Why use a variable at all?  Just plug the subquery in:

```
Select top 100 cnb.ndc_id, cnb.contract_num_val, cnb.quote_price, cnb.eff_dt, cnb.end_dt, cnb.discount_pct, cnb.rebate_pct
from [NDC_ATTR] ndc inner join
     CONTRACT_NDC_BRG cnb
     on ndc.attr_val=cnb.NDC_ID
where ndc.field_id = 69 and
      cnb.contract_ndc_brg_id in (select contract_ndc_brg_id
                                  from contract_ndc_brg join
                                       ndc
                                       on contract_ndc_brg.ndc_id = ndc.item_pk
                                  where item_id = @VALUE
                                 );
```